# How can I sort records ordered by datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`@comments` has 10 records sorted by `id ASC` now.
I wanted to reverse order simply, so I coded `@comments = @comments.reverse`

But I get this error message

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_count'
<%= page_entries_info(@comments, :entry_name => 'comment').html_safe %>
```

If I take off reverse and leave it as `@comments = @comments`, there won't be any problem. 
Why? and How can I sort it ordered by `created_at DESC`?

```
@comments = Comment.where(:user_id => user_ids, :commentable_type => commentable)

if params[:page].blank?
    params[:page] = ((@comments.count - 1)/10) + 1
    @comments = @comments.page(params[:page]).per(10)
else
    @comments = @comments.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end

@comments = @comments.reverse
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're receiving

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_count'
```

because `@comments.reverse` returns a plain array. You need a Relation object that has the pagination functionality. The best way to accomplish your sorting needs is to create a scope in your comments model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :reversed, -> { order 'created_at DESC' }
end
```

Then instantiate your comments by calling the scope:

```
@comments = Comment.reversed
```

You can call the `page` method on that `@comments` collection and the rest should work. You can chain your `where` like you had it before, so it would look like:

```
Comment.reversed.where(:user_id => user_ids, :commentable_type => commentable)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@comments = Comment.where(:user_id => user_ids, :commetable_type => commentable).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

ALso, your page calculation is bad can can result in float/fractional numbers.  If params[:page] is blank, just default to page 1 for the first page.

Comment: that's not what I don't wanted to:( If I do it first page will have the latest post

Comment: You asked how to sort order by created_at desc.  revise the question.  what do you want?  The newest posts chronologically or the newest posts ordered by id field?

Comment: I want them with 'ASC' order but `DESC' order within the same page. It's for SEO

Comment: With your way, the comment's url will be changed every time as users posts another comments. So I want to sort it only within 10 records.

Comment: So just select them out normaly, and then when you loop through them in your view, do `@comments.reverse.each` i

Comment: what if I'm not doing it in view? I want to create whole method in application_controller.rb then no changes within views

Comment: Isn't there any possible way to do it in controller?

Comment: Then you are doing it the wrong way.  If you want to reverse the sort for presentation reasons, then the reversal should be done in the presentation layer (the view)

Comment: ahh, the reason why I was saying. Because my rails app is already done but I have to replace all of the pagination part with it. It will be too much work. So I wanted to solve it in here.

Comment: I wanted to create new method being used in common. and just wrap all of the scopes in controllers with the new method. Then everything will be done with little work